# Multiple conditions on datatimeindex

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I m trying to create a bool with multiple conditions on a datetimeindex. Here is my example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2020-05-24', '2020-05-26', freq='1H', closed='left'))
mybool = np.logical_and(df.index.weekday < 5 , df.index.hour > 7 , df.index.hour < 20)
```

So mybool should be True for Mon-Friday for 12 hrs from 8am to 8pm. However this returns true on Mon-Fri from 8am to midnight. So it looks like the first two conditions are picked up but the third is not. But this also returns no error.

Comment: should it be <= 5 to include Friday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain your conditions with [bitwise ands](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators):

```
(df.index.weekday < 5) & (df.index.hour > 7) & (df.index.hour < 20)
```

Note that `np.logical_and` expects only two input arrays `x1, x2`. An alternative would be to use `np.logical_and.reduce` on a list of conditions:

```
np.logical_and.reduce([df.index.weekday < 5, df.index.hour > 7, df.index.hour < 20])
```